# AWS Lambda and SAM template

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam

We have a few lambdas created in the console that I want to move into a SAM framework.  For the first one I used sam init.  I copy/pasted the code into files in the project.  I then manually made the updates for layers/vpc/security/etc to the template.yaml file.  Is this the best approach or is there some way to autogenerate a SAM project from an existing lambda?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're on the correct track. There is **no tool** for autogenerating the SAM project from the existing resource at the moment.

But you can try using **AWS CloudFormer** for creating AWS CloudFormation templates from existing resources in your AWS account(**But Not Lambda yet!!**). But still, you need to make some tweaks for your AWS SAM template, which makes your work a little bit easy.